# Incorrect job search results?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, search

Visiting Scotland (from the US) I searched for jobs within 20 miles of Edinburgh, UK and got an empty result (see the screenshot below).

It seems unlikely there are no jobs in Edinburgh. In fact, in the lower right corner of the screenshot one can see an advert for a job with iZettle in Edinburgh.

[image]

It is of course possible that this is operator error, or a consequence of moving my laptop from the US to the UK.

Comment: Search results are selected by your current known location, companies state their preference when they create the ad.  You probably created a Developer Story that says that you still live in the US.  Or use a VPN that pipes through a US server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd assume the reverse: it's possible that there are currently no available *jobs opening* in Edinburgh, UK.

The ads you see is [iZettle](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/https-www-izettle-com), a *company* having offices in both Edinburgh, UK and Stockholm, Sweden.

However, the job they're currently offering is [a web developer based in *Stockholm, Sweden*](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/169190/web-developer-revolutionise-the-payment-izettle).

[Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?q=izettle&l=Edinburgh%2C+UK&d=20&u=Km) for *companies named iZettle within 20km of Edinburgh, UK* returned the expected result though.

Comment: I wonder if the employer's location in the ad is picked by the system from a list of places provided by the employer *to better match the viewer's listed location* or if it's really a case of the employer saying they're based in Edinburgh but also only having job opening(s) listed somewhere else in this case. You see this all the time (though not usually a list of locations *provided by* the ad author) on sites with lots of advertisements: "Hey, check out this crazy thing at <your local town name>" and it's highly annoying.

Comment: I guess I overestimated the likelihood of UK jobs appearing in Stack Overflow and mistakenly took the mention of Edinburgh in the advert to mean the job advertised was in Edinburgh,  Teach me to read more carefully (and not jump to conclusions).